# ANTLR4 Tokenizing the First Non-Whitespace Non-comment Char of a Line

Tags: antlr4

I am looking for a way to tokenize a '#' being the first non-whitespace, non-comment character of a line (this is exactly the same as the standard C++ preprocessing directives requirement). Notice the first non-whitespace requirement implying the # can be preceded by whitespaces and multiline comments such as (using C++ preprocessing directives as examples):

```
/* */ /* abc */ #define getit(x,y) #x x##y
```

and

```
/* 
can be preceded by multiline comment spreading across >1 lines

123 */ /* abc */# /* */define xyz(a) #a
```

The '#' could be preceded and followed by multiline comments spanning >1 lines and whitespaces. Other '#' can appear in the line as operators so being the first effective character in the line is the key requirement.

How do we tokenize the first effective # character ?

I tried this

```
FIRSTHASH: {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? ('/*' .*? '*/' | [ \t\f])* '#';
```

But this is buggy since an input like this

```
/* */other line
 /* S*/ /*SS*/#
```

is wrongly considered as 2 tokens ( 1 big comment + a single '#'). i.e. the `.*?` consumed the 2 two `*/` incorrectly causing the 2 lines combined as 1 comment. (Is it possible to replace the `.*?` inside multiline comment by something explicitly excludes `*/`?)

Answer (score 0):

I'd lex it without the restraint and check during parsing phase or even after parsing.

It may be not conforming to the grammar to put the '#' elsewhere but it doesn't invalidate the parsing => move it to a later phase where it can be detected more easily!

If you really want to do it "early" (i.e. not after parsing), do it during the parsing phase.
The lexing doesn't depend on it (i.e. unlike strings or comments), so there's no point in doing it during the lexing phase.

Here's a sample in C#.
It checks all 3 defines (first two are ok, the third is not ok).

```
public class hashTest
{

    public static void test()
    {
        var sample = File.ReadAllText(@"ANTLR\unrelated\hashTest.txt");
        var sampleStream = new Antlr4.Runtime.AntlrInputStream(sample);

        var lexer = new hashLex(input: sampleStream);
        var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource: lexer);
        var parser = new hashParse(input: tokenStream);
        var result = parser.compileUnit();

        var visitor = new HashVisitor(tokenStream: tokenStream);
        var visitResult = visitor.Visit(result);



    }
}

public class HashVisitor : hashParseBaseVisitor<object>
{
    private readonly CommonTokenStream tokenStream;

    public HashVisitor(CommonTokenStream tokenStream)
    {
        this.tokenStream = tokenStream;
    }
    public override object VisitPreproc(hashParse.PreprocContext context)
    {
        ;
        var startSymbol = context.PreProcStart().Symbol;
        var tokenIndex = startSymbol.TokenIndex;

        var startLine = startSymbol.Line;

        var previousTokens_reversed = tokenStream.GetTokens(0, tokenIndex - 1).Reverse();

        var ok = true;
        var allowedTypes = new[] { hashLex.RangeComment, hashLex.WS, };
        foreach (var token in previousTokens_reversed)
        {
            if (token.Line < startLine)
                break;

            if (allowedTypes.Contains(token.Type) == false)
            {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
            ;
        }

        if (!ok)
        {
            ; // handle error
        }

        return base.VisitPreproc(context);
    }
}
```

The lexer:

```
lexer grammar hashLex;


PreProcStart : Hash -> pushMode(PRE_PROC_MODE)
    ;

Identifier:
        Identifier_
    ;

LParen : '(';
RParen : ')';



WS
    : WS_-> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

LineComment
    :   '//'
        ~('\r'|'\n')*
        (LineBreak|EOF)
    -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

RangeComment
    :   '/*'
        .*?
        '*/'
    -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;




mode PRE_PROC_MODE;
PreProcIdentifier : Identifier_;
PreProcHash : Hash;

PreProcEnd :
               (EOF|LineBreak) -> popMode
           ;
PreProcWS : [ \t]+    -> channel(HIDDEN)
          ;
PreProcLParen : '(';
PreProcRParen : ')';
PreProcRangeComment
    :   '/*'
        (~('\r' | '\n'))*?
        '*/'
    -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;




fragment LineBreak
    :   '\r' '\n'?
    |   '\n'
    ;

fragment Identifier_:
        [a-zA-Z]+
    ;
fragment Hash : '#' 
    ;
fragment WS_
    : [ \t\r\n]+    
    ;
```

The parser:

```
parser grammar hashParse;
options { tokenVocab=hashLex; }

compileUnit
    :   (allKindOfStuff | preproc)*
    EOF
    ;

preproc :   PreProcStart .*? PreProcEnd
    ;

allKindOfStuff
    :   Identifier
    |   LParen
    |   RParen
    ;
```

The sample:

```
/* 
can be preceded by multiline comment spreading across >1 lines

123 */ /* abc */# /* */define xyz(a) #a 

/* def */# /* */define xyz(a) #a 

some other code // #


illegal #define a b
```